# Removing git tracker and all files from React App

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code

I tried

> rm .git
> but it doesn't work as it says it cannot delete its children files.

Comment: Try doing `rm -rf .git`

Comment: Tried..couldn't find rf something....Didn't Work basically

Comment: Try it in bash not in powershell

Comment: Thanks @KiprasT It worked.
If u want to, add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rmdir /s .git` should work if you are on Windows.

Comment: I tried in the app directory...It couldn't find it

Answer (score 3):

Select `bash` terminal and execute command: `rm -rf .git`

Flag `r` will go into folders recursively, while flag `f` will delete files without prompting you to confirm each file/folder deletion.